# Social Media sites preventing other sites displaying their pages in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, facebook, youtube

Last week at work we noticed that if you try and display a YouTube page in an iFrame you are shown a page stating that this is not allowed. A link is shown that takes you direct to the page. We looked at other social media sites, both Facebook and Twitter also do this.

I have two questions. One how is this done? My guess is it's a check something like:

```
if(window != top){
  // display 'error' page
}
```

The other question is why is this done? My first thoughts were maybe it was to do with security but the more I've thought about it, the more I think it's a legal thing or a marketing decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Websites don't want other websites stealing their content. I remember implementing something like this as far back as in the nineties. You pretty much answered your own question. However, it is also a security issue. At least with Twitter, there used to be some malicious sites, which would do the following:

1. Make some bs website with something about tweeting or posting something, showing some kind of form.
2. Include an iframe pointing to http://twitter.com/share?text=SPAM_TEXT_HERE
3. Position that iframe into a place where a button for the bs site's form would be.
4. Scroll the iframe so that only the "Tweet" button shows from the iframe.

This way they would get people tweeting their spammy tweets.

Comment: I thought I had a few reasonable guesses, but it's good to get some definite reasons. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in youtube policies, I give you the official answer by youtube's David Boyle and the correct embed options on api' s page `https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=it`

Hello YouTube API Developers,

This Wednesday, January 12, the YouTube.com web team will be
implementing a change to prevent websites from including the www.youtube.com
website on their pages via an `<iframe>` (or `<frame>`). Following this
change, an `<iframe>` pointing to www.youtube.com will cease to display
the YouTube web site, and instead will display a blank page.

While this change isn’t directly related to the YouTube API, we did
want to announce this change in advance on the off-chance any YouTube
API developers out there do include www.youtube.com on their site’s
pages via frames. We also wanted to make clear that this change is not
meant to affect the official `<iframe>` YouTube video embed API

```
(described at http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html),
```

which should remain fully operational. It is only intended to affect
non-embed API usage.

If you’ve been including www.youtube.com on your pages because you
were not sure how else to embed videos, this YouTube Help article
details the official methods of embedding:

```
http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171780
```

Best
Mario

Comment: Hi Mario. Thanks for replying but this doesn't tell me why they chose to implement it, only that they did implement it.

Comment: That said it does give extra info and advice with regards to YouTube so I've voted you up. I can see how it might help someone else. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How to Embed iFrame Code in Your WordPress Site (Manually and Using a Plugin)
Leave a Comment / guides / By qmk
Have you heard about inline frames (iFrames) lately and how they can help you share content on your website? If you run a blog or produce any web content, there are times when you probably want to share other people's content. more details [click here](https://www.vastlikes.com/)

iFrames make it possible to do this efficiently and securely.

Using iFrames, you'll be able to display things like videos and images without hosting them on your website.

In this post, we'll provide an overview of what iFrames are, what they do, and how to use them in WordPress.

Then, we'll show you how to embed them manually and use plugins. Table of contents

Using iFrames in WordPress
What are iFrames?
Things to know before you start using iFrames
How to Use iFrames in WordPress (3 Ways)

1. Embed the iFrame using the embed code
2. Use a text editor
3. Add an iFrame using a plugin
   You're ready to start using iFrames in WordPress!

**Using iFrames in WordPress**
You might wonder why you need to use iFrames to embed content when there are other ways.

On the one hand, you can simply copy and paste content into your website, right? Or for videos, just download and upload them to your post, page or media library?

While these methods work, they are not desirable. First, copying and pasting other people's content may violate copyright laws.

The second reason you shouldn't upload things like videos is that these files take up a lot of disk space and bandwidth, and can slow down your site.

Using iFrames will avoid both of these problems.