# "This application does not support integration with your profile."

Tags: html, iframe, facebook-apps

Past apps that I have built seem to work fine, but when trying integrate a simple HTML page embedded into an iframe, all I get is the above message ("This application does not support integration with your profile").

Any suggestions or direction helps.

Thanks!

Comment: A little more context might make it easier for you to get an answer: What sort of 'app'? Can you show us an example of your code? What have you done already to try fixing the problem?

Comment: Absolutely,so its just a simple .jpeg image that is loaded into an iFrame. the link below is the image with code.http://www.deststudios.com/client/cartoys/facebook/BirthdayBash.html?  All I have done to try as a fix is use the debug tool and swap out app ID codes using this URL that I pulled from Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL.  I just enter the required information and all I get is "This application does not support integration with your profile."  Im new to all of this so I am running out of things to try that I understand. Anything helps!

Comment: Ah, you mean a Facebook app. It's not something I'm familiar with, unfortunately. It's probably worth editing your original question to include the additional information.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that this question I asked previously might be useful.

[Social Media sites preventing other sites displaying their pages in an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924043/social-media-sites-preventing-other-sites-displaying-their-pages-in-an-iframe)